# Gradle Build Failed - Flutter

Tags: gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to run flutter application it gives this build error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.             
> Could not create service of type DefaultGeneralCompileCaches using 
  GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().
```

So far what I tried

- Flutter clean
- Invalidate & Restart
- Tried to stop and restart gradle daemon
- Copied classes to different project

Here are the dependencies, I am using

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
   sdk: flutter
 splashscreen:

 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 english_words: ^3.1.0
 http: ^0.12.0+2
 progress_dialog: ^1.1.0+1
```

I am pretty sure this has to do something with my current project because I tried to create a new project and it is working. I searched online but got nothing

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with one of the dependencies you imported inside your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: They were working before.

Answer (score 4):

**Gradle** is the build tool used in Android apps.

Try to install Gradle manually from their website. Here is the link: https://gradle.org/install/

If you are linux/Mac user then follow these steps:
*Simply open a new terminal and enter*:

```
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

$ sdk install gradle 5.6.2
```

Also don't forget to add PATH environment variable something like this

`$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.6.2/bin`

Comment: Gradle is fine with other project. I have kotlin project opened in another instance which is working but not my flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not need a gradle in the project. The gradle is needed only for android. So if you build your project using android project, try doing it by flutter project. And flutter already has gradle inside, so it will be set automatically.

Comment: Can you point out which part of your answer is the solution for my problem? Also, I've mentioned that I've created a sample project and is working fine but not my current project.

Comment: when I first start my first flutter project ,I had several proghlems with the gradle .so the solution which made me happy is rebuild the project with out the gradle . made life easier .

Comment: Sorry, but as I mentioned I tried cleaning/rebuilding, but that didn't work. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the same error after killing a gradle build while in progress (not a Flutter project).  After finding [this issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795) I discovered that there was a gradle process still running in the background (e.g. by using `ps -ef | grep gradle` on a mac). After killing the rougue process I was able to run gradle again.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the provided technique works simply downgrade your gradle build level. This will solve your problem.

```
dependencies {

 `classpath` 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

}
```